# TFS 2013 - Description HTML Field Can't Be Required

Tags: tfs, field, tfs-power-tools

Fellow TFS users and/or junkies,
We are using TFS 2013. When I add required for Description HTML (Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHTML), the default value still shows up as "As a  I want  so that ", THUS it doesn't require the user to fill anything in and it doesn't show up yellow. Sure, I could change the field, but we already have many things linked to Description HTML and can't risk changing the fields (reports and such are already setup). How would I change this so either: 
A. It is empty and will show up required OR
B. It requires the user to change the value

Things I tried:
Setting the value to empty. Won't allow me to have both empty AND required.
Setting Default Value to empty. Won't allow me to that either.
Setting Prohibited Values to the default text it has. Not allowed for the field.
Applying a WhenNotChanged rule for the field and setting it to required. It already has a value so it doesn't matter if it's required or not.
[image: Showing Description HTML field and Required with no Default Text]

[image: Default text I can't remove which voids the purpose of "required"]

Comment: I remember this default text, but I can't seem to see that in a template in tfs2013 update2. Which version are you using that I can repro this?

Comment: We are using TFS 2013 (No updates) and we are using the SCRUM 2013 template I believe

Answer (score 1):

I've just looked into a similar tfs machine.
It's just a defined "Default" rule but not in the "Fields" tab but in workflow tab.

In my case, it was in the initial transition rule.
To be specific:

Like you can guess, using Power Tools;

1. open the work item
2. go to the "Workflow" tab.
3. In the designer, double click the (most possibly) first transition element to view its settings
4. In the window opened, go to the "Fields" tab
5. If you see "Description" field there, double click it
6. Remove the "Default" rule

Now, you don't have a default text. You can set it "Required" and it'll be ok.

1. Close all, go to Fields tab of work item and set a required rule in a way as you expected initially.

Comment: I'll give it a shot later today and let you know if it works out. Thanks Beytan!